# Several loops in the same sub

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to figure out how could I, within the same sub, run several loops:
I have a set of excel file each of these files have to undergo some changes in their column A and O, every cell with the value "136" have to be replaced by a "174" under certain condition:

For  now what I've done this:

```
Sub REPLACE1()
Dim y As Integer
Dim wB As Workbook
Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("\")

For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

With wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R")
For y = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
If .Cells(y, "A") = 136 And .Cells(y, "B") = "320" Then
.Cells(y, "A") = 174

End If
Next y
End With


wB.Save
wB.Close

Next fileobj

End Sub
```

My problem is that when I try to do:

```
Sub REPLACE1()
Dim y As Integer
Dim wB As Workbook
Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("\")

For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

With wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R")
For y = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

If .Cells(y, "A") = 136 And .Cells(y, "B") = "320" Then
.Cells(y, "A") = 174

End If    

If .Cells(y, "O") = 136 And .Cells(y, "N") = "320" Then
.Cells(y, "O") = 174


End If
Next y
End With


wB.Save
wB.Close

Next fileobj

End Sub
```

Which means, include another "if" condition in the loop. None error message appears but no changes occured in my sheets.

I must miss something but I can figure out exactly what.

Comment: You placed your new If within the original If.  You need to add another End If to fix the problem.

Comment: Lack an **End If** in the second script?

Comment: Yes i forgot to put one End If it here, but the problem does not seem to come from here.

Comment: Your new If is still within the original If.  I think you need to move your End If.

Comment: I tried too, must be a problem with the format, this is weird

Comment: do it step-by-step on with pencil and paper ... it may help you

Comment: Ibo , It actually work now, thanks a lot, but i find it strange that only the format can have an influence ..

Answer (score 1):

You code is not formatted and you will miss a lot of simple problems. I had to format it and see if there is anything missing or not. Run this code and let me know if there is any error:

```
Sub REPLACE1()
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("\")

    For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files
        Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)

        With wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R")
            For y = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

                If .Cells(y, "A") = 136 And .Cells(y, "B") = "320" Then
                    .Cells(y, "A") = 174
                End If

                If .Cells(y, "O") = 136 And .Cells(y, "N") = "320" Then
                    .Cells(y, "O") = 174
                End If
            Next y
        End With

        wB.Save
        wB.Close

    Next fileobj
End Sub
```